# Изменить градиент элемента при заполняющихся input's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Имеется иконка в виде галочки серого цвета.
После заполнения одного из инпутов формы необходимо изменить градиент у галочки в процентном соотношении, исходя из кол-ва всех инпутов

Например, пользователь заполнил один инпут - градиент меняется на `(top, #b9b6b6 85%,#22d469 15%)`, при заполнении след. инпута снова изменение на 15, собственно, при заполнении всех инпутов, градиент галочки будет `(top, #b9b6b6 0%,#22d469 100"%)`

Как это можно сделать?

Форма

```
    <form method="post" id="s-1" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('home-form') }}" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="image" id="img-preview" value="">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <div class="faq-wrapper" id="friends_block">
                                                <div class="faq-item">
                                                    <a href="#" data-ix="show-faq-answer" class="faq-link-block w-inline-block">
                                                        <div class="faq-title" id="vk_block" style="text-align: center; font-size: 17px;">Мои друзья</div>
                                                        <div id="vk_api_transport"></div> <img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/theme/joke/images/arrow.svg?1') }}" class="faq-icon" style="transform-style: preserve-3d; transition: transform 200ms; transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);"> </a>
                                                    <div data-ix="hide-faq-answer" class="faq-answer-block">
                                                        <div class="list-group" id="users"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
    <center>                                    
    <div class="col-xs-6">

    <div class="loader_2" style="z-index: 99999;"></div>

    <div id="image">
     <img class="img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 350px; max-height: 200px; margin-bottom: 5px;"> 
     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label class="button w-button fileContainer" style="text-align: center; height: 35px; max-width: 200px;"> 
    Фото  <i class="icon-file-picture"></i>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="upload"> </label>
    </div>
        </center>                               </div>
                                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 mt">
                                            <div class="input-field field-news-firstname">
                                                <label for="from" style="display: none;">Имя:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control field underline-field w-input" id="news-name" placeholder="Введите имя" required> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 mt">
                                            <div class="input-field field-news-lastname">
                                                <label for="from" style="display: none;">Фамилия:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control field underline-field w-input" id="news-lastname" placeholder="Введите фамилию" required> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 mt alternate">
                                            <div class="input-field field-news-age">
                                                <label for="from" style="display: none;">Возраст:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control field underline-field w-input" id="news-age" placeholder="Укажите возраст" required> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 mt alternate">
                                            <div class="input-field field-news-city_id">
                                                <label for="from" style="display: none;">Город:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control field underline-field w-input" id="news-city_id" placeholder="Укажите город" required> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 mt">
                                            <section>
                                                <label for="class" style="display: none;">Пол:</label>
                                                <select name="gender" id="news-gender" class="cs-select cs-skin-border field underline-field w-input" required>
                                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Укажите пол</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Мужской</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Женский</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 mt">
                                            <section>
                                                <label for="class" style="display: none;">Шаблон новости:</label>
                                                <select name="template_id" id="news-portal_id" class="cs-select cs-skin-border field underline-field w-input" required>
                                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Шаблон новости</option> {% for template in templates %}
                                                    <option value="{{ template.id }}">{{ template.name }}</option> {% endfor %} </select>
                                            </section>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
<button type="submit" class="button full-submit-button w-button">Далее</button> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Функция, изменяющая стиль элемента

```
function appendCSSToElement(element, CssProperties){ // 
    var existingCSS = $(element).attr("style");
    if(existingCSS == undefined) existingCSS = "";
    $.each(CssProperties, function(key,value){existingCSS += " " + key + ": " + value + ";";});
    $(element).attr("style", existingCSS);
    return $(element);
}
```

Вызов функции, когда заполнен один из инпутов

```
appendCSSToElement("#progress_1.icon", { "background":"-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b9b6b6 100%,#22d469 0%)", "-webkit-background-clip":"text", "-webkit-text-fill-color":"transparent", "display":"initial" });
```

Событие формы onchange

```
    formOne.on('change', function (e) {
    var input = $(e.target).attr('name');
    var element = $('[name="' + input + '"]');

    var formInvalid = false;
    formOne.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
          formInvalid = true;
        }
    });

    switch (input) {
        case 'name':
            if (regexp_string.exec(element.val()) === null) {
                messageValid([{msg: 'Поле "Имя" содержит недопустимые символы!'}]);
            } else {
                element.css({"border-width": "0px"});
                validation.html('');
                progress_1.css({"color": "#b9b6b6"}); // СЕРЫЙ ЦВЕТ ГАЛОЧКИ     
            }
            break;
        case 'last_name':
            if (regexp_string.exec(element.val()) === null) {
                messageValid([{msg: 'Поле "Фамилия" содержит недопустимые символы!'}]);
            } else {
                element.css({"border-width": "0px"});
                validation.html('');
            }
            break;
        case 'age':
            if (regexp_int.exec(element.val()) === null) {
               // messageValid([{name: 'age', msg: 'Не допустимый возраст (от 12 до 50)!'}]);
                messageValid([{msg: 'Не допустимый возраст (от 12 до 50)!'}]);
            } else {
                var age = parseInt(element.val());
                if (age >= 12 && age <= 50) {
                    element.css({"border-width": "0px"});
                    validation.html('');
                } else {
                    messageValid([{msg: 'Не допустимый возраст (от 12 до 50)!'}]);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'city':
            if (regexp_string.exec(element.val()) === null) {
                messageValid([{msg: 'Город указан не корректно!'}]);
            } else {
                element.css({"border-width": "0px"});
                validation.html('');
            }
            break;
    }



});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте пример кода воспроизводимым, посмотрите как сделать [mcve]

Comment: @kizoso не совсем понял, как это сделать

Comment: Где в коде вы применяете свою функцию? А самое главное - зачем она, если вы используете jQuery в котором есть метод `css()`? В jQuery - `$(element).css(CssProperties)`

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft я новичек, и не совсем понимаю, как это можно сделать(

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite, Среди кнопочек формы ввода есть  та, которая создаёт сниппет (выглядит как лист с символами `<>`). В нём пишите JS, HTML, CSS так, чтобы получился рабочий пример. И уже на его основе говорите что не так или что Вы там хотите изменить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример как это вообще работать может:

```js
let gradient = {
  from: {
    color: '#fff',
    offset: 0
  },
  to: {
    color: '#000',
    offset: 100
  }
};

$('#from').on('input', e => {
  gradient.from.offset = +e.target.value;
  rebuild();
});
$('#to').on('input', e => {
  gradient.to.offset = e.target.value.trim() !== '' ? +e.target.value : 100;
  rebuild();
});

rebuild();

function rebuild(){
  $('#root').css('background', `linear-gradient(to right, ${gradient.from.color} ${gradient.from.offset}%, ${gradient.to.color} ${gradient.to.offset}%)`);
}
```

```css
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
<input type='number' id='from' placeholder='From' /> | <input type='number' id='to' placeholder='To' />
```

Comment: Не совсем то, но принцип понятен, спасибо!